# Calculate the run length encoding of a string

Tags: python, character-encoding

example if the string had "xxxyyz" the output would be 3x2y1z
I am not sure how to go about doing this question and I tried multiple methods but cant seem to get anywhere close to the output I want

```
s = input("Please type a sentence or word: ")
i = 0
count = 1
while len(s) <=i:
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
         count = count+1
         s1 = count + s[i]
```

first week learning programming and I know what im doing up there is wrong hopefully someone could help clear and possibly explain what I should do
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a version you could try. it uses [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two adjacent characters of the input string at the same time and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to be able to print what remains at the end of the loop:

```
strg = "xxxyyz"

mult = 1
lgth = len(strg)
for i, (prev, nxt) in enumerate(zip(strg, strg[1:])):
    if prev != nxt:
        print('{}{}'.format(mult, prev), end='')
        mult = 1
    else:
        mult += 1
    if i == lgth-2:  # print what is left at the end of the string
        print('{}{}'.format(mult, nxt))
```

the loop will run over

```
i (prev, nxt)
-------------
0 ('x', 'x')
1 ('x', 'x')
2 ('x', 'y')
3 ('y', 'y')
...
```

---

actually there is no need for the `enumerate`; `nxt` is accessible after the loop:

```
mult = 1
for prev, nxt in zip(strg, strg[1:]):
    if prev != nxt:
        print('{}{}'.format(mult, prev), end='')
        mult = 1
    else:
        mult += 1
print('{}{}'.format(mult, nxt))
```

Comment: thank you so much, now I just have to understand what enumerate and zip mean but it helps clear up all the other situations!

Comment: sorry, just another issue, when I put in xxxyyzz the output gives me 3x2y1y instead of 3x2y1z, I tried changing the "if i == lgth-2" and playing around wiht other sections but not sure why it gives y instead of z

Comment: ? ...i get `'3x2y2z'` for the input `'xxxyyzz'`.

Comment: sorry, just retyped it carefully and it was a mistake on my behalf!

Answer (score 0):

Use collections.Counter for it

```
import collections
collections.Counter(your_string)
```